# how to receive HTTP request, modify body, then post to another endpoint?

Tags: node.js

I'm attempting to write a simple service will

1. Receive a http request
2. Modify some values in the body
3. Then, post the data(headers + newly modified body) to another endpoint.
4. return the exact response from the new request to the client.

I have found a sample that does the http relay nicely, but I'm struggling with modifying the post before it's sent on? I'm able to get the contents of the post, but can seem to get my head around how to modify it before sending it on it's way.

```
var http = require( 'http' );
var qs = require( 'querystring' );

http.createServer( function ( req, resp ) {

    var h = req.headers;

    h.host = "webdbg.com";
    req.url = "/sandbox/FileForm.asp";

    var newRequest = http.request( {
        host: h.host, port: 80, path: req.url, method: req.method, headers: h
    }, function ( newResp ) {
            resp.writeHead( newResp.statusCode, newResp.headers );
            //as we receive our response from the new request, start writing it to this response.
            newResp.on( 'data', function ( respBody ) { resp.write( respBody ); });
            //once we have all the data from the new request stor writing it to this response.
            newResp.on( 'end', function () { resp.end(); });
        });

    var postData = "";
    //as we receive our body write it to the new request.
    req.on( 'data', function ( reqBody ) { postData += reqBody;  newRequest.write( reqBody )});//here I need to replace the values of the form post 
    //once we have all of our data from this request, stop writing it to the new request.
    req.on( 'end', function () { console.log(qs.stringify(qs.parse(postData))); newRequest.end(); });

}).listen(1337);
console.log( "Server running...");
```

I'm coming over from the dark side(C#) and as most, I'm struggling with the asynchronous nature of Node.js. With that, I'm committed to plugging away at the tutorials on Node School and Plural Sight until I get it! Any help you can provide with this would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to modify the response and relay it to the client?

Change the newResponse handler to modify the response from the remote server.

```
newResp.on( 'data', function ( respBody ) { resp.write( respBody ); });
```

to

```
newResp.on( 'data', function ( respBody ) { resp.write( MODIFY(respBody) ); });
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm wanting to modify the HTTP Post body that is sent to my server, before relaying it to the remote server.

Comment: @user3783214 You just need to write the MODIFY function to do your modifications. MODIFY will get called before resp.write executes.